# Dereferencing Pointer to Pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to run through a 2-dimensional array and update values using a pointer to pointer to int.

Swap function:

```
void foo(int ** vacancies, int **transfers, int transfer)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < transfer; i++)
    {
        (*transfers[i]) = 0;
        (*vacancies[i]) = 2;
    }
}
```

Declaration:

```
int ** vacancies = new int*[getVacancies(grid)];
int ** transfers = new int*[transfer];
```

Function call:

```
foo(vacancies, transfers, transfer);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to actually update any values, is there something I need to change?  Thanks!

Edit:

```
getVacancies(vacancies, grid, transfer);
getTransfers(transfers, grid, transfer);

    void getVacancies(int ** vacancies, int grid[][ROW], int vCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vCount; i++)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < ROW; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < COL; col++)
            {
                if (grid[col][row] == 0)
                {
                    vacancies[i] = &grid[col][row];
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the same for getTransfers.

Edit 2:

```
void getVacancies(int ** vacancies, int grid[][ROW], int vCount)
{
    int i = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < ROW; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < COL; col++)
            {
                if (grid[col][row] == 0)
                {
                    vacancies[i] = &grid[col][row];
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using `std::vectors`

Comment: What you are showing us appears correct.  Show more.

Comment: For example: how do you initialize these int arrays?  And how do you determine whether the values are not updated?

Comment: You're overwriting the same `vacancies[i]` each time through the inner loop.

Comment: So all `vacancies[i]` will point to the last `0` element in `grid`.

Comment: Oh, Barmar, you are right.  I have updated the code above, although it did not change the output.

Comment: Please don't change the question. Now my answer makes no sense, since readers can't see the original question that I was correcting.

Comment: Aren't you getting a compiler warning about trying to use the value of a void function?

Comment: `getVacancies(grid)` is wrong -- `getVacancies()` takes 3 arguments. And you can't use it in the assignment to `vacancies`, because `vacancies` is one of the arguments.

Comment: Did you mean to call a different function, that counts the number of vacancies in `grid`?

Comment: My apologies, I have reverted it, and added in your revision as a new edit.

Comment: Correct, I have overloaded getVacancies with 2 functions, the one you see above and one which simply counts the number of vacancies in grid.

Answer (score 1):

You have allocated only "one dimension". Those `int*` elements should point to arrays of `int` or just `int`s. Dereferencing these uninitialized pointers is undefined behavior.

Comment: But doesn't new int*[transfer] create a dynamic array of pointers?

Comment: Yes, but they don't point to anything. It doesn't even look like you need 2D arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is how you need to initialize your array. You shouldn't loop through `vacancies`, because that will fill each element with a pointer to the same element of `grid` (the last vacant one). Instead, you just want to loop through `grid`, and add each vacant element to the next entry in `vacancies`.

I've also changed the function to return the number of elements that were filled in. Alternatively, you could initialize `vacancies` to `nullptr` in each element, and test for this when looping through it later.

```
int getVacancies(int ** vacancies, int grid[][ROW], int vCount)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < ROW; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < COL; col++)
        {
            if (grid[col][row] == 0)
            {
                if (i >= vCount) { // Prevent overflowing vacancies
                    return i;
                }
                vacancies[i++] = &grid[col][row];
            }
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocate a two dimensional array like this (see [How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new)):

```
int** twoDimensionalArray = new int*[rowCount];
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; ++i) {
    twoDimensionalArray[i] = new int[colCount];
}
```

Comment: He's edited the question to show how he initializes the arrays. This isn't what he needs.